# How to detect bracet (at the end of line or new line)?

Tags: java

This is my code.

```
while(in.hasNext()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        in.hasNextLine();
        if (line.length() >0){
            int k = -1;
            k = -1;
            while(true){
                k = line.indexOf('\n' + "{", k+1);
                if(k<0)break;
                bracketNewLine++;
            }
            k = -1;
            while(true){
                k = line.indexOf(" {", k+1);
                if(k<0)break;
                bracketWithSpace++;
            }
        }
    }
```

if I have text file

```
if (...) {
}

and 

if (...)
{
}
```

output is:

- bracet end of line are: 1
- bracet new line are: 1

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Since you analyze the file line by line, I suspect that the line will never contain `'\n' + "{"`;

Answer (score 0):

You read the file line by line. Hence, there is no chance to find the character `\n` followed by another character in the same String. Hence, `'\n' + "{"` will never be found.

You can do it with simple regex :

```
for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/input.txt"))) {
  if(line.matches("\\{.*")) {
    bracketNewLine++;
  }

  if(line.matches(".* \\{")) {
    bracketWithSpace++;
  }
}
```

Comment: output bracketNewLine is 0, but in my text file I have "{" in a new line (separate)

Comment: @Anonymous I think that you are skipping the first line (because of the first `in.nextLine()`). I edited my answer to show how I read the input file. Can you test? On my computer, I get the expected answer : `bracketNewLine = 1`

Comment: Yeah, I am tested
But, in my code using Scanner like this (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66286522/Screen%20Shot%202559-03-18%20at%204.53.03%20PM.png)

Comment: @Anonymous You are testing on `test2.java`. Are you sure that it is the same text file as in your question?

Comment: I am sure because I use the same files between test1 & test2

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regex like this:

```
String patternInLine = ".+\\{$";
String patternNewLine = "^\\{":

Pattern p1 = new Pattern(patternInLine);
Pattern p2 = new Pattern(patternNewLine);

while(in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    in.hasNextLine();

    Matcher m1 = p1.match(line);
    Matcher m2 = p2.match(line);
    if(m1.match())
    {
        //inLine++;
    }
    else if (m2.match())
    {
        //newLine++;
    }
    else
    {
        //other cases
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `nextLine()` method, you already have the source line by line. The only thing you should do is checking those lines in every loop with existing String methods : `startsWith()` , `endsWith()`. If we assume that you are correctly obtaining line string in each loop, inside of that while block should be like that:

```
if(line.startsWith("{"))
    bracketNewLine++;
if(line.endsWith("{"))
    bracketWithSpace++;
```

P.S.1 `hasNext()` method does not assure us that we have one more new line.

P.S.2 searching a string with fixed size space is not a true approach. You may use regex instead of that : `^[\s]*{`